# How do accumulators work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Hello i am trying to understand how do accumulators work by creating the following method :

It receives a number and it creates a tuple of: `(sum [0..nr], [0..nr])`. For instance, given `4`, it should return `(10, [0,1,2,3,4])`.

This is the code I have:

```
accu :: Int -> (Int, [Int])
accu 0  = (0, [0])
accu nr = go (0, []) nr where   --I do not get this line, mainly the first argument
            go (s,ls) 0  = (s, 0:ls)
            go (s,ls) nr = go (s+nr, nr:ls) (nr-1)
```

I do not understand how the accumulator changes its value, since it is not a function, and thus shouldn't it be immutable? Shouldn't it be like a constant in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go` is a function that is locally defined using the `where` keyword and then used directly in the `accu` function. Have a look here:
http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where

That means the accumulator does not really change, it is just a different accumulator in each recursive call to the `go` function. The last line will recursively call the `go` function with a new accumulator value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it simply.

```
(\n -> (sum [0..n], [0..n])) 4
(10,[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Or this is cleaner but longer.

```
(\n -> (\l -> (sum l, l)) [0..n]) 5
(15,[0,1,2,3,4,5])
```